# How can I pass a pre-defined pipeline build parameter to a template in Azure DevOps pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Template:

```
parameters:
- name: PathPrefix
  displayName: 'Path prefix'
  type: string
  default: ''

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: ${{parameters.PathPrefix}}**/$(Build.DefinitionName).sln
```

Pipeline:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: devops
    name: foo/devops
    type: git
    ref: master

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - refs/heads/*

jobs:
- job: Job_1
  displayName: Agent job 1
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-latest
  steps:
  - checkout: self
  - template: azure/pipelines/pipeline.yaml@devops
    parameters:
      PathPrefix: $(Build.DefinitionName)
```

Run error during the restore step:

```
##[error]No files matched the search pattern.
```

Even setting `verbosityRestore: detailed` on the restore step doesn't give me any more information.

If I don't set `PathPrefix`, it seems to use the default empty string and find the solution file (in some cases). However, if I do set the prefix, which is needed in some repos, it can't find the file. I've tried various ways of referencing the parameter within the template (`${{}}`, `$()`, `$[]` and others) and different ways of specifying it within the pipeline, including hard-coding the path (though I want to use the variable instead), but nothing works.

I thought maybe variables would work instead, so I also tried specifying variables in the pipeline and using them in the template, but that results in the same error. Defining the variable in the template gave me a compilation error for the template (unexpected token 'variable' or something similar).

Comment: A shot in the dark, have you tried adding quotes to escaping the special chars?
`'${{parameters.PathPrefix}}**/$(Build.DefinitionName).sln'`

Answer (score 0):

Look at what you're passing and mentally expand the results.

`${{parameters.PathPrefix}}**/$(Build.DefinitionName).sln`

If `Build.DefinitionName` is *foo*, and you pass that in as `PathPrefix`, then what you get is:

`foo**/foo.sln`

It looks like you want an extra forward slash in there, so you get `foo/**/foo.sln`.

Comment: I tried it with and without a trailing slash in PathPrefix and neither worked.